# Element to element multiplication and shift by one

Tags: python, list

I have two list:

```
a = [[A,1],[B,2],[C,3]]
b = [[X,4],[Y,5],[Z,6]]
```

I am trying to multiply element to element in such way that i keep "a" as it is and shift "b" by one position in each iteration.

```
1st iteration:
1*4+2*5+3*6 = 32
2nd iteration:
1*5+2*6+3*4 = 29
3rd iteration:
1*6+2*4+3*5 = 29
```

Store all the results in list `c`. I expect c to be:

```
c = [32,39,29]
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: It may make sense to use a `collections.deque` for `b` instead of a list

Answer (score 3):

One simply way to do this is using slicing:

```
c = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    c.append(sum(x*y for x, y in zip(a, b[i:] + b[:i])))
```

Sample run:

```
In [1]: a = [1, 2, 3]
   ...: b = [4, 5, 6]
   ...: 

In [2]: c = []
   ...: for i in range(len(b)):
   ...:     c.append(sum(x*y for x, y in zip(a, b[i:] + b[:i])))
   ...:     

In [3]: c
Out[3]: [32, 29, 29]
```

In your case you may need to replace `x*y` by `x[1]*y[1]`.

This however creates a copy of `b` at every iteration. You may want to simply use loops:

```
import itertools as it

c = []
for k in range(len(b)):
    res = 0
    for i, j in enumerate(it.chain(range(k, len(b)), range(k))):
        res += a[i]*b[j]
    c.append(res)
```

Or you could use a `collections.deque` to store the indices:

```
from collections import deque

c = []
b_indices = deque(range(len(b)))

for _ in range(len(a)):
    c.append(sum(x*b[j] for x, j in zip(a, b_indices))
    b_indices.rotate(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution. This is modifying b in every iteration.

```
lst =[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    value= [a[i][1]*b[i][1] for i in range(len(b))]
    lst.append(sum(value))
    b.insert(0,b.pop())
print lst
```

Output:

```
[32,29,29]
```

For full solution as you  expect, see this:

```
lst =[]
summed =0
length =len(a)
for x in range(len(a)):
    print "Iteration ",x+1
    for i in range(length):
        print a[i][1],"*",b[i][1],
        summed +=a[i][1]*b[i][1]
        if i<length-1:
            print "+",

        else:
            print "=", summed
            lst.append(summed)
            summed=0
    b.insert(0,b.pop())

print lst
```

Output:

```
Iteration  1
1 * 4 + 2 * 5 + 3 * 6 = 32
Iteration  2
1 * 6 + 2 * 4 + 3 * 5 = 29
Iteration  3
1 * 5 + 2 * 6 + 3 * 4 = 29
[32, 29, 29]
```

Comment: where can i display individual multiplying elements? eg. 1*4 2*5 3*6

Comment: You have to iterate though the list then.

Comment: I want to display 1*4, 2*5, 3*6 before computing sum. Can you tell me how?

Comment: I could help you, there was no need to post a different question

Comment: I need it urgently, so i had to. Appologies. I have deleted it now. can you please help?